# After xsl change: Unable to display this web part

Tags: content-query-web-part, item-styles

I am experiencing a new issue that I am not quite sure how to fix. We have a SP2013 online subscription. The overall problem is that I wish to display rich text using a Content Query Web Part. The CQWPs I have take info from a list item that is formatted with tables or bullet points. I edited the itemstyle.xsl to add a template I liked. I then edited ContentQueryMain.xsl to add in output escaping so that the code isn't displayed like so:
[image: CQWP in a tabbed content editor]

As you can see, the actual code for the list item is being displayed, but only on a different account. On my developing account (as a power user) I get the following view, exactly what I want.
[image: Developer account CQWP view]

What really tripped me up about this is that when I go to the style of the webpart properties, they are different for each user. On my account, I had all of the normal styles plus my own:
[image]

On the second account(which I gave permission as an owner), it only shows the normal styles:
[image]
Ideas anyone?

Comment: Did you reference a CSS file, and if so is it published and visible to the other user?

Comment: did I reference a CSS file in... The itemstyle.xsl? the only place I reference css is in the content editor that groups the CQWPs into tabs

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out... Needed to check in ItemStyle.xsl so it is accessible to everyone.